# github Auth using RestRequest in github

Tags: c#, .net, github-api

I am getting the error on request to a github.

"Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). Check https://developer.github.com for other possible causes"

This is my code:

```
var client = new RestClient
            {
                BaseUrl = "https://api.github.com",
                Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_username, _password)
            };
            //client.AddDefaultHeader("User-Agent", "http://developer.github.com/v3/"+_username);

            _restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
            {
                Resource = _resource,
                RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
            };
           // _restRequest.AddHeader("User-Agent",);
            _restRequest.AddBody(new { title = form["feedbackmessage"], body = html, labels = new List<string> { _defaultlabel } });
            _restRequest.AddHeader("User-Agent", "http://developer.github.com/v3/#" + _username);
            var response = client.Execute(_restRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [GitHub Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required), all API requests MUST include a valid User-Agent header.

What i have done was adding this User-Agent to my HttpClient like this:

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Other");
```

and I did a normal request, for example:

```
var json = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
```

and it worked pretty well.

Another nice reference for it, you can check [here](https://gist.github.com/bryanbarnard/8102915).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with similar issue today. As far as I understood from GitHub doc, it doesn't have to be URL-like style, like in your example. Having just `_username` as `User-Agent` value is enough.

It didn't work for me with `_restRequest.AddHeader("User-Agent"...` as well and started working only after adding:

```
client.UserAgent = _username;
```

or

```
var client = new RestClient
            {
                BaseUrl = "https://api.github.com",
                Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_username, _password),
                UserAgent = _username
            };
```